# Creating multiple matrices with a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I would like to create `ncol(y)` number of matrices taking each column from `y` matrix and replicating it `rep` number of times. I am not doing the for loop right though. To reiterate, below I would like to get three separate matrices, the first one would have values of 1 to 100 repeated 200 times (they come from the first columns of y), second would have vector 101-200 repeated 200 times (2nd column of y) as well and the third one would have values 201-300 repeated 200 times (3rd column of y). Preferably the output name would be matrix1, matrix2 or a list.

```
y <- matrix(1:300,100,3)
rep = 200

for (i in 1:ncol(y)) {
        newmatrix <- replicate(rep,y[,i])
        valuematrix[[i]] <- newmatrix
}
```

Comment: `valum[[paste0("matrix", i)]] <- newmatrix`

Comment: I guess you need to initialize with `valuematrix <- list()` or `valuematrix <- vector("list",ncol(y))` before the loop

Comment: @Khashaa : I am getting an error: Error in valum[[paste0("matrix", i)]] <- newmatrix : 
  object 'valum' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the initialization of valuematrix. You can do this through

```
valuematrix <- list()
```

just before the for loop.

You might also consider using lapply to solve this problem. It automatically stores the matrices in a list.

```
y <- matrix(1:300, 100, 3)
rep = 200

matList <- lapply(1:ncol(y), function(i) replicate(rep, y[,i]))
```